# Groovy: Replace / in Path with \

Tags: groovy, escaping, backslash, slash

How would you replace `/` with `\` in Groovy? So that 
`"//10.1.1.1/temp/test"` becomes `"\\10.1.1.1\temp\test"`.

`"//10.1.1.1/temp/test".replaceAll(/'\\/'/,'\\')` <-- ? doesn't work

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at this `"//10.1.1.1/temp/test".replaceAll("/","\\\\")`. `"\\\\"` makes a single backslash.

Comment: watch out for toString methods in iterators...

f = new File('c:/temp/test/')
        f.eachFileMatch { it.split("\\.")[1].length()==3 } { 
        
            println it.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","/")
            }

Answer (score -1):

> Please check this

```
 String path = 'D:/folder1/folder2/yourfile' 
 String result = path.replaceAll( "/","\\");
```

> Finally you get result like

```
'D:\folder1\folder2\yourfile'
```

Comment: It does not work: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing